# Where am I going wrong, analyse the existence and uniqueness of $y'=y^\frac{1}{2}$ $y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I ended up with the solution $y=\frac{x^2}{4}+xc+c^2$, and using the fact that $y(0)=0$ this simplifies to $y=\frac{x^2}{4}$.  So a solution exists and it is unique.

Also, I was trying to apply existence uniqueness theorems to the problem but had no success. Using Picard's theorem was inconclusive because if $f(x,y)=y^{1/2}$ then $\frac{df}{dy}$=$\frac{1}{2y^{1/2}}$, and this is not continous on any rectangle centred on $(0,0)$

Comment: The main issue I am having is applying existence-uniqueness theorems to the problem.

Comment: $y(x)=0$ is also a solution.

Comment: Oh true, so then how can I use the theorems to show a solution exists but that the solution is not unique?

Comment: You can use the Peano existence theorem since $f$ is continuous. For unicity, according to what I know there is no general theorem when Picard theorem is not satisfied.

Comment: So I have $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{4}$, and $(0,0)$  is an interior point of an infinite number of rectangles that the function is continuous. And there exists a $h \gt 0$ such that $y(0)=0$ has a solution on the interval $∣x-x_0∣ \le h$

Comment: So I am having trouble with the theorem. Am I supposed to work out the value of $h$?, in this instance it seems as though $h$ can be any value because a parabola is continuous on the entire number line.

Comment: The theorem itself does not give you much information about the interval of existence.

Comment: It seems that you are confusing properties of solution and properties of tangent field. The tangent field corresponding to $y' = y^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not Lipschitz-continuous at points with $y=0$ -- that's why you can't apply existence-uniqueness theorem here.