# Is this a correct application of the Picard-Lindelof theorem for $y'=y^{2/3}$ with $y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(x,y)=y^{2/3}$ so $y_1^{2/3}-y_2^{2/3} \lt K|y_1-y_2|$ and this is true for all $K \gt 0$ which means the above differential equation has only one solution.

Now I  worked out the solution for the above differential equation and got $y=\frac{x^3}{27}$ as the only solution.

Comment: I just realized I have arrived at a contradiction because $y(x)=0$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually quite simple. Using your symbols, let $y_1 = 0$ and then confirm that $\forall K > 0 \; \exists y_2 > 0:$

\begin{equation}
\lvert y_1^{2/3} - y_2^{2/3} \rvert = \lvert y_2 \rvert^{2/3} > K \lvert y_2 \rvert = K \lvert y_1 - y_2 \rvert
\end{equation}

This contradicts Lipschitz continuity which is the requirement responsible for the uniqueness result in Picard-Lindelöf's theorem.
Intuitively this happens, because the derivative of your $f$ with respect to $y$ is $\textit{unbounded}$, when $y$ goes to zero.
A good way to picture this is to draw the graph of $g(y) = y^{2/3}$ and then also to draw the graph of $h(y) = K \cdot y$ for $K > 0$. Then you will find that no matter how large your $K$, there is always a piece of the graph of $g$ lying $\textit{above}$ the graph of $h$. This is $\textit{exactly}$ the negation of local Lipschitz continuity at $y = 0$.

Comment: How were you able to eliminate $y_1^{2/3}$ in your first step?

Comment: By not going for the general case, but instead setting $y_1 = 0$. If we can disprove Lipschitz continuity at $y_1=0$ then $f$ cannot be Lipschitz for all $y$.

Comment: That is wrong, you probably didn't zoom in enough. Check values of $y < 0.005$. Or see [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7By%5E(2%2F3),5y%7D,%7By,0,0.01%7D%5D)

Comment: Yes you're right I deleted my comment because I realized I misread what you had said. Do you mind checking out my other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897923/where-am-i-going-wrong-analyse-the-existence-and-uniqueness-of-y-y-frac12?noredirect=1#comment3893757_1897923?